# Java While Loop

Tags: java

Whenever I try to run this loop, I receive:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
    at test.readNumber(Lab2.java:28)
    at test.go(Lab2.java:15)
    at test.main(Lab2.java:7)
```

I'm trying to repeatedly prompt the user until the keyboard input is positive. Can anyone tell me how I can go about doing that without running into error?

```
    public int readNumber() {
        int x = keyboard.nextInt();
        while (x < 0) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive number.");
            x = keyboard.nextInt();
        }   
        return x;
    }
```

Comment: This code seems fine.

Comment: "InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range" http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are either not supplying an integer or giving a value for an integer which is out of range.

Comment: You were right, turns out I was giving a value that was out of range. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

It is always a good idea to check the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()). The exception is thrown if input data doesn't match the "Integer" pattern. Wrap input with try/catch:

```
public int readNumber() {
    int x = -1;
    while (x < 0) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a positive number.");
        try {
            x = keyboard.nextInt();
        } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
            // oops, wrong input
        }
    }   
    return x;
}
```

Comment: breaks if initial input is not an int

Answer (score 1):

```
public int readNumber() {
        int x = -1;
        do {
            try {
               System.out.println("Please enter a positive number.");
               x = keyboard.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
              // normally you always want to handle the exception but in this case it is okay because mismatched input is the same as a non-positive integer input
            }
        } while (x < 0);
        return x;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the EOL after reading te int value.

```
public int readNumber() {
        int x = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.readNextLine();
        while (x < 0) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive number.");
            x = keyboard.nextInt();
            keyboard.readNextLine();  
        }   
        return x;
    }
```